# Does squeezed light gravitate repulsively?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, speed-of-light, quantum-optics, squeezed-states

Since there are alternate regions of positive and negative energy densities in squeezed light, does that mean that the negative energy density parts gravitate repulsively? Since the stress energy would turn negative.

Comment: I don't think 'squeezed light' means what you seem to think it means.

Comment: @JonCuster I think the misunderstanding is that squeezed light has a *quasiprobability distribution* with positive and negative parts, but that those don't correspond to positive and negative *energy densities*

Comment: Can you elloborate your question

Comment: I was thinking, since negative energy densities lead to gravitational repulsion, that the negative energy density regions in squeezed light also should have a gravitational repulsive effect.

Comment: An example of stress-energy tensor calculations for a squeezed state can be found in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0109061),  sect. IV. And yes, there are indeed *negative energy densities*.